# Import PDF in CorelDraw2017 with image inside wrong

Tags: pdf, corel-draw, graphic-styles

I received a pdf from a company which needs to see it in Corel Draw 2017. So I can see the pdf as per the below image.

[image]

and for me it's perfect!
But when I import the pdf into Corel Draw 2017 I see something wrong 
[image]

Why is my image in another position?

Does anyone have any suggestions for me?

Thanks

Luna

Here is the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxkdldMLEGQGQlhnNXZkejBMQTg/view) to get the PDF

Comment: Perhaps you could share the PDF file, because I don't know how else anyone would be able to check.  There are all kinds of software which can output PDFs, and you don't mention which software was used to prepare it.  Can you find out perhaps if you don't know?

Comment: @BillyKerr I don't know which is the program used to generate PDF file. Let me share the pdf [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxkdldMLEGQGQlhnNXZkejBMQTg/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

One important thing to understand in most electronic documents is that they are not a finished product. They are a set of instructions on how to operate and display them.

In this case, your document is using a **fill pattern**, the roses, and that leaves the door open to be "reinterpreted".

To have an acurate PDF you need to minimize the options, the interpretations. That is why you have diferent specifications of the PDF.

In this case the person making the PDF could "rasterize the fill pattern" with an apropiate resolution or generate a more standarized PDF, like an X1 or X3.

One thing **you** can do is "print" the document to another file using adobe reader using for example PDF creator, and export to a raster format, and in case you still need the vectors you can open them in Corel and insert the generated image in the previous step.